# Task manager to kill processes

Tags: windows-10, taskmanager

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\cturn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\try_march_3v6ffkv9.exe'
```

On Windows 10, I want to use task manager to kill the program using the "resource" try_march_3v6ffkv9.exe

So, eh, how do I do that then?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this is happening?**
you're trying to access a file, and it's not accessible because another process (or even the same process) is doing something with it (and it didn't allow any sharing).

**How do I fix it?**
[Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) is a tool which will let you see open file handles. When you kill the offending programs (or close the file) you can avoid this error.